# Why doesn't my click handler function run as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make an extension for an website I do not own.
It is supposed to always listen and click the button when I click the key. It should be copied in the console.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $( document.body ).trigger({
            type: 'keypress',
            which: 32,
            keyCode: 32
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: It could be many things. You mention that this is an extension for a third-party website. Is it a userscript, for example to be injected with something like Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey? Or is it a literal extension?

Comment: I where trying rn with the console. I didn't create any extensions so far

Comment: I suspect that the reason it is not working is because you're calling a jQuery function `$(...)` before the script had a chance to load.

Comment: how can i load it? Sorry im not used to the whole console thing. Its my first time doing something for a third party website